# Why Is my code not outputting the string from the if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, output

Here is my code: https://plnkr.co/edit/HFyKq2JZipwAAST0iNAt?p=preview
Why is it not outputting the result of the if statement to the tag with ID "WA"
Here's the IF Statement separate from the code linked above:

```
if (demlean.WA <= 5 && demlean.WA >= -5) {
        if (demlean.WA > 0) {
          var lWA = "Tossup, Tilt D";
        } else if (demlean.WA < 0) {
          var lWA = "Tossup, Tilt R";
        } else {
          var lWA = "Absolute Tossup";
        }

      } else if (demlean.WA > 5) {
        if (demlean.WA <= 10) {
          var lWA = "Lean D";
        } else if (demlean.WA <= 17) {
          var lWA = "Likely D";
        } else {
          var lWA = "Safe D";
        }
      } else {
        if (demlean.WA >= -10) {
          var lWA = "Lean R";
        } else if (demlean.WA >= -17) {
          var lWA = "Likely R";
        } else {
          var lWA = "Safe R";
        }
 }
.... // more code
```

Comment: Have you checked if `demlean.WA` is not `undefined`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you familiar with [the `switch` statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch)?

Comment: For starters, you never set demlean.WA to anything.  Lots of better ways to structure this, of course.

Comment: so many `var lWA` in so little code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay finally I'm able to run your code, Here is the modification what I've done. 
First,

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: dDe is not defined
    at calc ((index):140)
    at submit ((index):153)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):167)
```

So I changed this line to `DE: dDE,`. Then another error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: demlean is not defined
    at lean ((index):45)
    at calc ((index):146)
    at submit ((index):153)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):167)
```

`demlean` is a local variable. so i need to pass this to lean function.

```
    .....
    var geba;
    var tda;
    /* If Statement for determing lean in variable lSTATE */
    function lean(demlean) {
    .....
    .
    .
    .
    DE: dDE,
    MD: dMD,
    NY: dNY,
    VT: dVT,
    ME: dME,
    HI: dHI
  };
  // passing demlean here.
  lean(demlean);
```

Hope this help. Here is the updated code link: https://plnkr.co/edit/fGlSmDEWNEtKEZ7sLgUC?p=info

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted there is a closing `}` missing at the very end

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

- The last closing curly brace is missing :-)

## Solution

- Add the missing curly brace :-)

```js
var demlean = {
  WA: 5
};

if (demlean.WA <= 5 && demlean.WA >= -5) {
  if (demlean.WA > 0) {
    var lWA = "Tossup, Tilt D";
  } else if (demlean.WA < 0) {
    var lWA = "Tossup, Tilt R";
  } else {
    var lWA = "Absolute Tossup";
  }

} else if (demlean.WA > 5) {
  if (demlean.WA <= 10) {
    var lWA = "Lean D";
  } else if (demlean.WA <= 17) {
    var lWA = "Likely D";
  } else {
    var lWA = "Safe D";
  }
} else {
  if (demlean.WA >= -10) {
    var lWA = "Lean R";
  } else if (demlean.WA >= -17) {
    var lWA = "Likely R";
  } else {
    var lWA = "Safe R";
  }
}

console.log(lWA);
```

See? now your code runs as expected.